# Very Strange Behavior about accessing private methods in PropertChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, dependency-properties

Ok! I'm just asking this out of curiosity, because it is very strange to me.

For the sake of argument, let's just say that I've defined a `DependencyProperty` and a `private` method in a class named `DynamicGridControl` like this :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomFactorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomFactor", typeof(double), typeof(DynamicGridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnZoomFactorPropertyChanged)));

...

private void forceAdornerRender()
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Of course, I have an `static` event handler in the class that goes like this :

```
private static void OnZoomFactorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (DynamicGridControl)d;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        vm.forceAdornerRender();
    }
}
```

The question is, why am I able to compile this piece of code without even a single error or warning?! I'm accessing a **private method** of the class, which certainly I shouldn't be allowed to. Is there something that I'm missing? Is there a rule in OOP that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Title should be "Why I can call access private methods of the class from static method in the same class"... but it will sound soo wrong. Side note: please try to provide complete samples for questions - simplified version showing whole class would be easier to read.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, you're right, maybe the whole class is easier to read.

Comment: What are these "rules of OOP"? Why do you think the C# language must conform to them?

Comment: @mikez Please read my comments under the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* access `private` members on an instance of the same class, even within `static` members.

The ability to access private members on another instance of the same class comes into play when implementing `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable<T>`, *etc.*

```
public class ClassA : IEquatable<ClassA>
{
  private int _value;

  public bool Equals(ClassA other)
  {
    return _value == other._value;
  }
}
```

Access from `static`s specifically are used in operators:

```
public class ClassA 
{
  private string _value;

  public ClassA(string value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }

  public static ClassA operator +(ClassA first, ClassA second)
  {
    return new ClassA(first._value + second._value);
  }

  public static implicit operator string(ClassA a)
  {
    return a._value;
  }
}
```

A related tidbit: you can access `private` members of an outer class from a nested class.

```
public class ClassA
{
     private string _foo = "foo";

     private class ClassB
     {
          public string Bar(ClassA a)
          {
                return a._foo;
          }

     }
}
```

The question was posed: does this violate OOP?
I don't really see that it does. A `private` member means it is accessible from within a class, and in all of these examples, it is being accessed from within the same class. I think the risk of breaking encapsulation and reducing cohesion is greater without this feature, as we would be forced in some situations to expose more implementation-specific information publicly than is warranted for a given model.

Comment: But isn't it somehow against the rules of OOP? Why should I be able to access private members of an outer class?

Comment: You are not accessing an outer class.  Both methods are part of the same class.

Comment: @NathanA yes, Indeed in this example I am, but what about what you told about nested classes?

Comment: @Arashv, your question said that both methods were defined in the same class, which means you are NOT dealing with an outer-class scenario.  It's no different than when non-static methods access static-methods.  Private methods can access all private methods inside the same class.

Comment: +1 for useful samples. @Arashv - you are suggesting that method of the class should not know anything about internal structure of its own class... While it indeed possible but will make encapsulation much harder as Jay pointed in the answer.

Comment: @NathanA Thanks for the good explanation. I think I get it now, I knew that there were 2 rules, but just didn't combined them in the right way. 1. Static methods cannot refer to `this`. 2. A private member can have access to other private members. Combine them and you can have a `private static` member that can access other private members, given the correct instance! voila!

Comment: @Arashv - for future questions when you invent your own concept (like "rules of OOP") please consider explaining it in the original post instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't invent a concept! Haven't you read my last comment? They are rules of OOP. I just didn't put them in the correct order to come to the correct conclusion. By the way this site is created for people to get answers to their questions, no matter how expert or beginner they are at the concept. So assuming that I'm a beginner in this (which  I don't think so), your behavior seems inappropriate. :)

Comment: @Arashv - search for [Rules of OOP](http://www.bing.com/search?q=rules+of+OOP) and see if your definition comes up often enough. If not - you are inventing your own concept. Usually something like SRP would be considered "rule of OOP", but "static methods cannot refer to this" does not look like "rule of OOP" to me.

Answer (score 0):

Static members of a class can still access private instance methods of that same class, assuming you have a reference to the instance.

For example, the following works just fine:

```
class TestClass
{
    public static void TestStaticMethod()
    {
        TestClass instance = new TestClass();

        instance.PrivateMethod();
    }

    private void PrivateMethod()
    { 
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: but my class is not static.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Static classes mean you can have only static members, but non-static classes doesn't mean you can't have static members.

Comment: No, I was referring to the BOLD static in the first version of your answer, before you edited it. Anyway, Now I KNOW what the rule is, but isn't it somehow against the rules of OOP?

Comment: Ya, sorry. that was confusing which is why I removed it.  No, it doesn't necessarily break any rules of OOP.  You'll find that most (if not all) OOP languages support this, including C++.  Do some more research of static vs non-static for clarification.  The only between a static and non-static method is that you have reference to a `this` (`me`) keyword in a non-static method.